# Pointers and self incrementing arguments in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments

Keep in mind that I'm brand new to pointers.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have `value` incremented by a double value (in this case, .013) every time it iterates through this for loop:

```
/***********************************************************************************
@name:      fill_array

@purpose:   fill all elements in range 'begin' to 'end' with 'value'

@param:     double* begin   address of first element of the array range

@param:     double* end     address of the next byte past the end of the array range

@param:     double  value   the value to store in each element

@return:    void
***********************************************************************************/

void fill_array(double* begin, double* end, double value) {

    for( ; begin < end; begin++)
        *begin = value == 0.0 ? 0.0 : value;
}
```

An example of driver code that doesn't work (I am only providing this so that I might better communicate what I'm trying to accomplish):

```
double dataValue = 3.54;

double* currentData = &dataValue;

fill_array(begin, end, *currentData+.013);
```

Of course, all values that are stored in the array are 3.553.

Would I need to create a function with a return value to pass as an argument, into the formal parameter 'value'? Or could this be accomplished using only pointers?

Comment: You are not doing anything to increment `value`. Also, your ternary operator assignment seems pointless. It is the same as `*begin = value;`. Also, the documentation of the function is quite at odds with your description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I probably should have included that I have a default argument set to 0.0 for value in the function prototype. I'm aware of how to accomplish this by modifying the function. I want to be able to pass a dynamic argument into value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply increment value in each iteration:

```
for( ; begin < end; begin++) {
    *begin = value == 0.0 ? 0.0 : value;
    value += 0.013;
}
```

If you wan't 0.013 to be an dynamic, you should add another argument to your function (e.g. `double incrementer`).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid changing the function at all. I want to know how to accomplish this from outside of the function.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible without changing the function.

Answer (score 1):

> value incremented by a double value (in this case, .013) every time it iterates through this for loop:

Well, `value` is the function parameter provided by the caller, so the caller can modify it like this:

```
fill_array(begin, end, *currentData += .013);
```

If you don't want the calling code to modify the value, then you've got to make some other changes, because given...

```
fill_array(begin, end, *currentData+.013);
```

...the `value` parameter is provided with a temporary result from the addition, and there's no non-temporary variable that `fill_array` could ask for control of such that it could add to it and see the impact on the next call.  This can be solved in several ways, using pointers...

```
void fill_array(double* begin, double* end, double* p_value) {
    for( ; begin < end; begin++)
        *begin = *p_value;
    *p_value += 0.13;
}
fill_array(begin, end, currentData);
```

...or using references...

```
void fill_array(double* begin, double* end, double& value) {
    for( ; begin < end; begin++)
        *begin = value;
    value += 0.13;
}
fill_array(begin, end, *currentData);
```

Comment: The purpose of fill_array() is to fill all elements with the same exact value. What I'm trying to accomplish is to set different, incremental values through each iteration by means of some dynamic argument, without changing the function. I'm mostly just curious if this is possible.

Comment: @user3548076: oh... as you say, `fill_array` is designed to set all the doubles to the value, and "without changing the function", well, the function won't change O_o.  Not possible.  Arguments of type `double` are not and can not be made "dynamic" in any related sense.  With just a change to a user-defined type for the `value` argument, `fill_array` could act as discussed, having `value` increment itself each time it's used (e.g. `operator double() { return n_ += 0.13; }`).  Similarly, `template <typename T> void fill_array(double* begin, double* end, T& value)` allows enough freedom.

Comment: Functions do what the code in the function does. You can't change what the function does without changing the code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can not use function fill_array to do the task. But you can overload it specially for the task. For example

```
void fill_array( double *begin, double *end, double init, double incr ) 
{
    init = init == 0.0 ? 0.0 : init;

    if ( begin != end ) 
    {
        *begin = init;

        while ( ++begin != end ) *begin = init += incr;
    }
}
```

Or even you can have only one function if you will define the last parameter as having a default argument.
For example

```
void fill_array( double *begin, double *end, double init, double incr = 0.0 ) 
{
    init = init == 0.0 ? 0.0 : init;

    if ( begin != end ) 
    {
        *begin = init;

        while ( ++begin != end ) *begin = init += incr;
    }
}
```

So if you call it for example as

```
fill_array( begin, end, 3.54 );
```

it will behave as your original function.

If you call it as

```
fill_array( begin, end, 3.54, 0.13 );
```

it will behave as you are trying to achieve.